# How to pass a Rails variable into a route

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my show page I would like to change the route of a 'view more' button based on the value of a variable. For instance, if I'm looking at a building in Tampa Florida on the show page and I click 'view more', I want to go back to locations_tampa_path to see the full listing of buildings in Tampa again. However, I would like the path in the link to change based on the city of that particular building:

**something like this**:    location_#{@location.city}_path

*What is the best way to do this?*
Thanks in advance for any help given.
**My controller**:

```
class LocationsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @locations = Location.all
  end
  def new
    @location = Location.new
  end
  def create
    @location = Location.new(location_params)
    if @location.save
      flash[:notice] = "New location added"
      redirect_to root_path
    else
      flash.now[:error] = 'Cannot send message'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
  def jacksonville
    @locations = Location.where(:city => "Jacksonville")
  end
  def stpetersburg
    @locations = Location.where(:city => "St. Petersburg")
  end
  def orlando
    @locations = Location.where(:city => "Orlando")
  end
  def tampa
    # @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @locations = Location.where(:city => "Tampa")
    @photo = Photo.new
  end
  def show
    @location = Location.find(params[:id])
    @photo = Photo.new
  end

  private

  def location_params
    params.require(:location).permit(:name, :description, :address, :city, :featured)
  end
end
```

**Routes**

```
get 'locations/tampa', to: 'locations#tampa'
get 'locations/jacksonville', to: 'locations#jacksonville'
get 'locations/orlando', to: 'locations#orlando'
get 'locations/st_petersburg', to: 'locations#stpetersburg'
resources :locations do
 resources :photos, only: :create
end
```

Answer (score 3):

You're repeating yourself in your controller where you don't need to. It seems like you want a parameterized route:

In your routes.rb:

```
get "locations/:location", to: 'locations#show_location', as: :location_path
```

Then, you can pass `location` as a parameter in your view/controller:

```
location_path(location: @location.city)
```

And you can have a simple `show_location` action in your `LocationsController`:

```
def show_location
    @location = Location.find_by(city: params[:location])
    @photo = Photo.new

    if @location
       render @location.city
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response! I posted the relevant code from my routes.rb file, I'm still learning Rails and have not used a configuration like this yet. Could you explain how this works, its a little over my head. Are you suggesting I remove the separate city actions?

Comment: If I understood this more I would love to refactor my code an implement this,  I was able to make this work with my existing code by doing: location_path(@location.city.downcase), I'm sure this isn't ideal but its working for now.